# How to limit the rows in the result set of a bunch of RETURN QUERY in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `plpgsql` function performing several `RETURN QUERY` instructions. In my case this appends rows of one `bigint` column to the result set that will be returned by the function with the last `RETURN`.

Now, a new feature is forcing me to add the `_limit` argument to the function, limiting the number of returned rows.

How can I access the result set and limit it before issuing the last `RETURN`?

Although is a very general question, I am including the source code for if it helps.

```sql
create or replace function get_subcategories_by_category (
  _category_id      bigint,
  _include_category boolean default false,
  _recursive        boolean default false,
  _limit            int default 2147483647
)
returns setof bigint 
stable language plpgsql as $$
declare
  _child_id bigint;
begin
  -- return the source category
  if _include_category then
    return query
    select id from cnt_category where id = _category_id;
  end if;
  
  -- loop over the passed category children
  for _child_id in 
    select tc.id 
    from   cnt_category tc
    where  tc.parent_id = _category_id and
           tc.is_listable
  loop
    -- recursively look for every children childrens
    case
      when _recursive then 
        -- recursion
        return query
        select get_subcategories_by_category (_child_id, true, true, _limit);
      else
        -- retrieve children
        return query
        select _child_id
        limit _limit;
    end case;
  end loop;
end;
$$;
```